# How many official super saiyan transformations are there already?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

ok, so there are so many transformations and states in Dragon Ball already, that now it's hard to tell what's an official transformation and what's not. According to a japanese magazine spoiler of the upcoming episodes a new one could be just right on the way,

> Super Saiyan 3 for the super saiyan green/super saiyan berserker of Kale, which I assume it isnt the same transformation than the regular super saiyan 3

So, how many official super saiyan transformations are there already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Super Saiyan
2. Ascended Saiyan(Super Saiyan 2)
3. Super Saiyan 3
4. Super Saiyan 4(Not canon)
5. Legendary Super Saiyan (Not canon)
6. Super Saiyan rage(Future trunks)
7. Super Saiyan Berserker(Kale's transformation)
8. Super Saiyan God
9. Super Saiyan Blue
10. Super Saiyan Rose

// Additional

1. Mystic/ Ultimate Gohan ( I wouldn't call it an actual super saiyan transformation.)
2. Ultra Instinct Goku (His new aura seemed to indicate it was a new transformation).

Comment: What about Kale's calmed version of the super saiyan berserker (with no blank eyes and so bulky form). What about Kale's version of the SSJ3 (already stated in a japanese magazine it's coming). What about ultra super saiyan (Vegeta calls it an useless transformation once). Those should count as different transformations or not?

Comment: We do not know what Kale's transformation exactly is until she manages to control her current power. SSJ3 is an existing transformation, even if Kale or Caulifla gets it, it would be no different than the SSJ3 Goku and Gotenks have. Finally, the ultra super saiyan is not really a transformation. You could consider it as an unmastered SSJ2 transformation since it's only a power up, so I wouldn't really consider than an official transformation.

Comment: I think Ultra Instinct is not a transformation, but a technique or rather, a form. It's a power to be unlocked by training and not something to just attain by being forced to the limits and screaming at the top of your lungs. As is said by Whis, Goku was able to unlock it by breaking through his potential barrier while clashing with the spirit bomb's energy.

Comment: +Pratyush Manocha Ultra Instict is a skill but it is used in the form of a transformation by goku. This can be compared to Gohan's mystic transformation. Although it's only his potential being unlocked, we still see a new aura and the bang of hair drop down when he uses that power. If goku utilised Ultra instinct as a skill, he would've been able to utilise it while he is using SSJ or even in his base form. We see a new auro and the color of his eyes change. Hence it is a form of transformation.

Comment: Ultra Instinct doesn't fit in this list as it is nothing ki related and it isn't a super saiyan form. It is a state of the body that Goku unlocked by coincendence. Mystic/Ultimate Gohan is comparable to kaio-ken in terms of powering up so it isn't super saiyan related either. I wont edit them out of the answer due to the interesting comments that other users might find significant to know.

Comment: I'd like to disagree with you over here. Ultra Instinct is still in it's budding stage, and what was shown in the anime is, incomplete. The reason being that Goku had an aura while the original poster showing him in this state has no such aura. As for using it in SSJ, I'd like to say that it'd be useless and just a wastage of energy and hence, won't be used coupled with another form. None of this makes it a possible candidate for a transformation though. Now, if you want to argue that since it's incomplete, it's still a transformation, then it'd be useless to discuss it further.